# Powershell 2.0 Web-Request Alternative to API Gateway

Tags: powershell, curl, aws-lambda, powershell-2.0, windows-xp

I want to pull information from amazon aws using API-Gateway.
I have created a Lambda Function which generates information and converted the function to an API-GATEWAY.

I want to make invoke-webrequest call to obtain the information. the web-request will contain the following information to pass to get the info from the api-gateway: AWSURL, APIKEY, Data

I have created and tested the invoke-webrequest in Powershell 3.0 below is the code

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{"X-Api-Key" = "<key>"} -Method PUT
              -Body "<data>" -Uri <awsURL>
              | Select-Object -Expand Content
```

Here is the real problem.

Most of my machines are on Windows POS 2009 I have created the script to work in powershell 2.0 and tested on my windows 10 machine and works fine

```
  function ConvertFrom-Json20([object] $item){
    add-type -assembly system.web.extensions
    $ps_js=new-object system.web.script.serialization.javascriptSerializer

    #The comma operator is the array construction operator in PowerShell
    return ,$ps_js.DeserializeObject($item)
}

$awsUrl = "<awsURL>"

$urlHeader = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($awsURL)
$urlHeader.Headers.Add("X-Api-Key","<APIKEY>")
$urlHeader.Method = "PUT"

$data = "<DATA>"

$requestStream = $urlHeader.GetRequestStream()
$streamWriter = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($requestStream)
$streamWriter.Write($data)

if ($null -ne $streamWriter) { $streamWriter.Dispose() }
if ($null -ne $requestStream) { $requestStream.Dispose() }

$res = $urlHeader.GetResponse()

$streamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $res.GetResponseStream()
$result = $streamReader.ReadToEnd()

$resultFromJson = ConvertFrom-Json20 $result
Write-Host $resultFromJson
```

However when I take the script to run on the windows XP POS 2009 it does not work. The Windows XP POS 2009 is using powershell 2.0. I get a getResponse() error check below

```
    Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send."
At line:24 char:30
+ $res = $urlHeader.GetResponse <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:26 char:73
+ $streamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader $res.GetResponseStream <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (GetResponseStream:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:27 char:34
+ $result = $streamReader.ReadToEnd <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ReadToEnd:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I believe this might be to do with windows XP POS Webservices not liking the response back or something  and as a ALTERNATIVE i can use cURL but I really want to do this using windows powershell 2.0 scripting

Can someone please provide their knowledge and experience in this as I have tried to do this for so long. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try testing using the appropriate target version of PowerShell - `powershell -version 2 .\your-script.ps1`. You may also want to look at the error by diving into the $error object to find what is going on. It may be that you don't have valid certs for a TLS connection on the POS box as an example.